# ksql get distinct values in a column

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

How do I achieve in ksql

```
select distinct(`columnName`) from stream_name;
```

without using a table? I don't want to have a table compacted topic in my broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an endless stream. An aggregation is needed. Without a table, events will be silently ignored, e.g

> `COLLECT_SET(col1) => ARRAY`
> Returns an array containing **the distinct values of `col1` from each input row** (for the specified grouping and time window, if any).

However,

> The size of the result ARRAY can be limited to a maximum of `ksql.functions.collect_set.limit` entries, and **any values beyond this limit are ignored silently**.

---

> don't want to have a table compacted topic in my broker

You already have at least one, by default - `__consumer_offsets`